# Add delay to JS animated text

Tags: javascript

I got a code from codepen ( https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrqmPg ) for a auto typing text animation. 
I would like for my text animation to start after a certain time delay (like 5 seconds)

I have only rudimetal coding knowledge (I'm a designer, not a programer) therefor any help would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

```
function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
   if (colors === undefined) colors = ["#fff"];
    var visible = true;
    var con = document.getElementById("console");
    var letterCount = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var waiting = false;
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
   target.setAttribute("style", "color:" + colors[0]);
    var wordsInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
   if (words.length == 0) {
   window.clearInterval(wordsInterval);
    return;
 }

if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
  waiting = true;
  target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var usedColor = colors.shift();
    //colors.push(usedColor);
    var usedWord = words.shift();
    //words.push(usedWord);
    x = 1;
    target.setAttribute("style", "color:" + colors[0]);
    letterCount += x;
    waiting = false;
  }, 1000);
 } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
    waiting = true;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       x = -1;
    letterCount += x;
      waiting = false;
      }, 1000);
   } else if (waiting === false) {
    target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
    letterCount += x;
   }
  }, 120);
    window.setInterval(function() {
  if (visible === true) {
    con.className = "console-underscore hidden";
   visible = false;
  } else {
    con.className = "console-underscore";

     visible = true;
   }
  }, 400);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this?

```
setTimeout(() => {
consoleText(['Hello World.', 'Console Text', 'Made with Love.'], 'text', ['tomato','rebeccapurple','lightblue']);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try below code and let me know is that something you were looking.

```
function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
   if (colors === undefined) colors = ["#fff"];
    var visible = true;
    var con = document.getElementById("console");
    var letterCount = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var waiting = false;
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
   target.setAttribute("style", "color:" + colors[0]);
    var wordsInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
   if (words.length == 0) {
   window.clearInterval(wordsInterval);
    return;
 }

if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
  waiting = true;
  target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var usedColor = colors.shift();
    //colors.push(usedColor);
    var usedWord = words.shift();
    //words.push(usedWord);
    x = 1;
    target.setAttribute("style", "color:" + colors[0]);
    letterCount += x;
    waiting = false;
  }, 5000);
 } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
    waiting = true;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       x = -1;
    letterCount += x;
      waiting = false;
      }, 1000);
   } else if (waiting === false) {
    target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.
I used the code from @confusedGuy below and it did the job.
Thank you VERY much for your help :)